# Ветка вариантов ответа в PyTelegramBotApi

Tags: python, telebot

По команде /start бот выдает следующий текст:

```
1. Инфо
2. Время
```

При отправлении любой из цифр бот выдает другой текст, где цифры 1 и 2 имеют совершенно другую функцию(например, после нажатия цифры 1 бот отправляет следующий текст:)

```
1. Мое имя
2. Мой создатель
```

И уже здесь при отправлении любой из цифр бот выдаст совершенно иной текст

Как такое можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию `bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, next_step_handler)`. Где `msg` - это результат отправки прошлого сообщения, а `next_step_handler` - функция, что будет обрабатывать следующий шаг.